# How do I change text color to a gif (background-clip) on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since weeks I'm trying to figure how do I write my script:-

```
function Myfunction() {
  document.getElementById('d').style.weblitbackgroundClip ="url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/BurningFlame0.gif')";
  document.getElementById('d').style.webkitbackgroundClip ="text";
}
```

and it's not working when I click a button with `onClick="Myfunction"`

is there something wrong with my script or it will just wont work on the internet?

that '**d**' is my text's id

Comment: You should use `background` property for setting background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `()` to `onClick="Myfunction"` and you need to set your text to `color: transparent`

```js
function Myfunction() {
  var dStyle = document.getElementById('d').style
  dStyle.backgroundImage = "url(https://media.giphy.com/media/edYeOfmb9zaIo/giphy.gif)";
  dStyle.backgroundClip = "text";
  dStyle.webkitBackgroundClip = "text";
  dStyle.color = 'transparent'
}
```

```css
#d {font-size: 60px; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div id="d" onClick="Myfunction()">
  Burning Flame
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

Put this in your styles:

```
<style>
    #container {
        background:no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 100%;
        color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
    }
</style>
```

And should have some tag structure like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>hello world</h1>
    </div>
    <button onclick="Myfunction()">click on me</button>
</body>
```

And finally in your scripts write:

```
<script>
    function Myfunction(){
        document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/BurningFlame0.gif')";
    }
</script>
```

```js
    function Myfunction(){
        document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/BurningFlame0.gif')";
    }
```

```css
    #container {
        background:no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 100%;
        color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <h1>hello world</h1>
    </div>
    <button onclick="Myfunction()">click on me</button>
```